# How to get an RGB hex code in or out of an InDesign RGB colour swatch?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I've been using InDesign (CS6) for designing responsive web layouts and, while it makes some things easier to convert to CSS (such as paragraph styles and character styles), colours are surprisingly awkward.

I've got my final swatches just right, and I want to transfer them to CSS, but I can't find an easy way to get the RGB hex value of a particular swatch out of InDesign.

Double-clicking the swatch just gives me the RGB sliders, and double-clicking the selected fill/stroke colour just gives this dumbed-down colour picker which lack hex codes:

[image] [image]

Is there any easy way to work with hex codes in InDesign (CS6) when using RGB?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check this post:
[Color picker in InDesign](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/21226/color-picker-in-indesign)

Illustrator and Photoshop's UI has a hex display. While InDesign does not.

You can use Adobe's **kuler/color**. It's an extension that you can enable from the Window menu then Extensions, that can give you the hex codes you need without having to exit InDesign.

[color.adobe.com](http://color.adobe.com)

The button below marked "A" below imports the currently selected fill colour, giving you the hex codes in the section marked "B". Alternatively, you can paste the hex codes into "B", then when you've filled the set, use the button marked "C" at the bottom to create swatches from them.

[image]

Comment: Okay, this works, thanks! I hope you don't mind me editting in an image and a few details to make it more of a complete answer

Comment: Yep, that's no problem! Kuler/Color is also available online. @ color.adobe.com.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there is a way to use Hex codes with the colour picker.

However, you can easily convert the given decimal values RGB into Hex values with any programmer  calculator (even with the windows calculator).

Hope it'll help.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to find the same info. And another way to do it is use this online converter! Very easy!

https://www.rgbtohex.net/

Take the numbers from Indesign and type into that website and you'll get your hex #. I just found this and I'm not associated; just wanted to pass it on in case it helps someone else. I google lots of questions like this so I know what it's like always searching for answers. :)

Comment: The OP can already see the values. She is looking for something like copy and paste or export I understand. So going online and typing those values in yet another application is not a wrong answer but probably not the best solution; we shall see.