# Is there a way to create/modify colors in InDesign with an HSL or HSB picker?

Tags: adobe-indesign, hsb

CMYK, LAB, and RGB are all perfectly fine ways to pick colors, but for many purposes I find HSL (or HSB) to work better.

Is there a way to add/display an HSL/HSB picker in InDesign? Right now I copy the RGB color, switch to another app and paste the color, modify the HSL, copy the RGB, and then back to InDesign to paste it back in.

(There is [a version of this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/21226/color-picker-in-indesign), but it's quite old and doesn't directly address what I'm looking for.)